# Send mail via powershell without authentication

Tags: powershell, smtp, sendmail

I was using nant to send mail and it is working fine - something like

```
<mail 
    from="Test@b.c" 
    tolist="A@b.c" 
    subject="Test" 
    mailhost="myhost.mydomain.com"
    isbodyhtml="true"
    message= "${Test}">
</mail>
```

I didn't have to use any kind of authentication.

Now when using powershell it seems I am forced to use authentication - something like this would fail:

```
Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Subject "Test" –Body “Test (body) -SmtpServer "myhost.mydomain.com"
```

I would get the following message:

```
Send-MailMessage : No credentials are available in the security package
```

Am I missing some way to send mails without specifying credentials if the server supports that?

Edit:
I've also tried the answer here to send anonymous mails but it just times out:
[send anonymous mails using powershell](https://serverfault.com/a/543115)

Comment: If your server supports unauthenticated email then you are doing the right thing by not specifying credentials. So given that, you either now need to specify credentials OR they changed something with the ports and you might need to specify what port.

Comment: I don't think they changed anything because the nant script still runs without specifying credentials.
I am still new to powershell so I am not sure if the credentials are required though.

Comment: What is the context from which you are running this PowerShell command?

Comment: I am running powershell as admin if that's what you mean @Bill_Stewart
trying the code in ISE and in powershell.exe

Comment: Your question appears to be answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/543052/

Comment: In my latest edit I've mentioned this page - it just times out.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to call nant from powershell and pass it the mail to send? Seems quite convoluted especially because I am actually replacing a nant script with a powershell one but if that's the only way to send mails without authentical that might be only answer. I don't want to add credentials because they expire every 30 days and we aren't able to create a user that has no password expiry.

Answer (score 3):

Sending mails using Powershell v1 method works fine without authentication as shown [here](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/powershell-how-to-send-email/)

My Powershell version is 5 yet this is apparently the way to go, unless someone has another idea.

```
$smtpServer = "ho-ex2010-caht1.exchangeserverpro.net"
$smtpFrom = "reports@exchangeserverpro.net"
$smtpTo = $to
$messageSubject = $subject
$messageBody = $body

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$messagesubject,$messagebody)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I was looking for another issue and found this question here...
As @AngelicCore already explained one approach,
Here is another one if someone using Outlook dektop app...
The mail sent will appear in your outbox.*

**using outlook object**

```
Try
        {
        #Email structure
        $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
        $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
        
        #Email Recipients
        $Mail.To = "abc@domain.com;xyz@domain.com"
        $Mail.Cc = "tuv@domain.com; pqr@domain.com"
        
        #Email Subject
        $date = Get-Date -Format g
        $Mail.Subject = "Subject here $date"
        
        #Email Body
        $Mail.Body = "Body Here"
        
        #Html Body
        $Mail.HTMLBody == "<html> HTML Body Here </html>"
        
        #Email Attachment
        $file = "C:\path\xyz.txt"
        $Mail.Attachments.Add($file)
        
        
        $Mail.Send()
        Write-Host -foreground green "Mail Sent Successfully"
        
    }
    Catch
    {
        write-host -foreground red $error[0].Exception.Message 
        
    }
    
    pause
    exit
```